# Internet Connection in Android

Tags: android, android-internet

I have work on Application That use Internet.

- It contains XML parsing from url.
  than
- Showing Progress Dialog While parsing
  time.
- Stop dialog when parsing is done.
- set TEXT(Data) in ListView.

my issue is that, When device is connected to internet than my Apps works fine But when Device is not connected to internet "Progress dialog" is running for infinite time.

i want to stop dialog if device is not connected to internet or wifi. how to do this?
Any idea?
 Sorry guys.... I have change my mind i want to check internet connection when i click on button. what i have tried so far is..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homelayout);
        mclip = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clip);
        mclip.setClickable(true);
        mclip.setFocusable(true);

        mclip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)              getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
               //if it is connected to internet than start Another Activity.
                startActivity(new Intent(ListViewExample.this, ClipOfDay.class));
                } else if (netInfo == null) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListViewExample.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Connection Problem");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("You are not connected to Internet");
                    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            }
        });
       }
```

But this is not working.if device is not connected to internet than i want to show AlertDialog. otherwise it will start Activity.      can Anybody tell me what to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check network connection
A simple code for checking connection

```
ConnectivityManager cMgr = (ConnectivityManager) con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            String status = netInfo.getState().toString();
            if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) {
               //DO you work
            } else {
                Log.e("error", "No connection available ");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these two methods to check connectivity:

```
Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE).getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE).getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
```

then parse the results returned to know whether the connection is available.
If its available, then only do the things and put the dialog box.

alternatively, you could also pop the dialog box up, and before doing any network action, check for connectivity with these methods, and if connection isn't available, hide/cancel the dialog box and display an error message.
else, go for the network action.
and yes, always have a try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

- First check if internet or wifi is connected, then run your code
- Use try, catch, in case some exception occurs because of connection error, remove dialog in catch block.

This can be one way of doing this..............
Hope it helps.......

Comment: you are right but how can i check for that? i am new to android so i have no idea about how to check internet connection. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts    ,   try response send by Eddie